# ¿Cómo decirle a JavaScript que cambie una imagen que muestro debajo de un vídeo en los momentos del vídeo que yo le indique?

Tags: javascript, video, img

tengo un vídeo, debajo muestro el instante de reproducción y debajo tengo una imagen. Bien, necesito que esa imagen vaya cambiando en ciertos momentos concretos del vídeo y es esta última parte la que no logro sacar.

HTLM:

```
<video id="player" controls width="720" poster="img/ImagenInicial.png" loop>
<h2>Instante de reproducción: <span id="tiempo">X</span></h2>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", segundos);
function segundos() {
    let video = document.getElementById("player");
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){                  
    document.getElementById("tiempo").innerHTML = video.currentTime;});}
```

He probado muchas cosas, como esto:

```
//<button onclick="plause()" onclick="sincro()">Reproducir/Pausar</button>
function sincro(){
    let segundo = ["0", "7", "12", "17", "23", "27", "31", "32"];
    let imagenes = ["img/Imagen01_000.jpg", "img/Imagen02_007.jpg", "img/Imagen03_012.jpg", "img/Imagen04_017.jpg", "img/Imagen05_023.jpg", "img/Imagen06_027.jpg", "img/Imagen07_031.jpg", "img/Imagen08_032.jpg"];
    let video = document.getElementById("player");
    for (i=0; i<segundo.length; i++) {
        if (segundo[i] = video.currentTime){
            let nuevaImg = imagenes[i];}
        document.getElementById("diapo").src = nuevaImg;}
```

O esto:

```
  let video = document.getElementById("player");
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
            if (video.currentTime = 0) {
                document.getElementById("diapo").src = "../img/Imagen01_000.jpg";
            }
        });
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
            if (video.currentTime = 7) {
                document.getElementById("diapo").src = "./img/Imagen02_007.jpg";
            }
        });

        //...

        video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
            if (31 < tiempo){
                document.getElementById("diapo").src = "./img/Imagen08_032.jpg";
            }
        });
```

Y nada me funciona. Ojalá podáis ayudarme.
¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Los *"errores"* que veo son:

- Te falta cerrar el tag `video`
- Te falta el `src` al video (*aunque puede que si lo tengas*)
- La propiedad [`current`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) es un:

  > Un valor de punto flotante de precisión doble que indica el tiempo de reproducción actual en segundos.

Corrigiendo estas cosas tus códigos funcionan.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", init);

function init() {

  let video = document.getElementById("player");
  let segundo = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  let imagenes = ["img/Imagen01_000.jpg", "img/Imagen02_007.jpg", "img/Imagen03_012.jpg", "img/Imagen04_017.jpg", "img/Imagen05_023.jpg", "img/Imagen06_027.jpg", "img/Imagen07_031.jpg", "img/Imagen08_032.jpg"];
  
  let tiempo = document.getElementById("tiempo");
  let imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    tiempo.innerHTML = video.currentTime;
    imagen.innerHTML = imagenes[Math.floor(video.currentTime)];
  });
}
/**/
```

```html
<video id="player" controls width="400" src="//samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4" loop></video>
<h2>Instante de reproducción: <span id="tiempo">X</span></h2>
<div>Image SRC: <span id="imagen"></span></div>
```